# Can I combine array destructuring and .trim()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am having an array of strings coming from a CSV file which I destructure in my node.js app.

Now I need the strings trimmed with .trim() but I wonder if there is an immediate way to do this. The below doesn't work:

```
// writing object with returned arrays retrieved from CSV
  playerRecordsArr.forEach((playerRecord) => {
    const [id.trim(), customFlag.trim(), countryCode.trim()] = playerRecord;
    resultObject[steamID] = {
      playerData: { customFlag, countryCode },
    };
  });
```

I guess the way to do it would be this, but I'd lose the destructuring goodness:

```
// writing object with returned arrays retrieved from CSV
  playerRecordsArr.forEach((playerRecord) => {
    const id = playerRecord[0].trim();
    const customFlag = playerRecord[1].trim();
    const countryCode = playerRecord[2].trim();
    resultObject[steamID] = {
      playerData: { customFlag, countryCode },
    };
  });
```

Comment: `playerRecord.map(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` can be used to transform all elements of an array, but I would recommend to do apply `trim` individually at the place where you are using the value:

```
for (const [id, flag, country] of playerRecordsArr) {
    resultObject[id.trim()] = {
        playerData: { customFlag: flag.trim(), countryCode: country.trim() },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const playerRecord = ['   one      ', 'two ', 10000];

const trimIfString = x => typeof x === 'string' ? x.trim() : x;

const [id, customFlag, countryCode] = playerRecord.map(trimIfString);

console.log(playerRecord)
console.log(playerRecord.map(trimIfString))
```

Comment: brilliant. This works in my example where all array elements are strings. Is there also a way to apply this partially to prevent .trim() is not a function? Or would you have to protect it via an if x = string?

Comment: @Christian-Peter I've edited my answer to handle it.